# I'm getting opencv error (-216:No CUDA support) even after succesfull build

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to install opencv with gpu support on windows10, and so I have built it with cmake with WITH_CUDA=ON
yet i am getting this error
`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:106: error: (-216:No CUDA support) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function 'throw_no_cuda'`
it's my third time reinstalling the opencv library

I have reinstalled cudnn, and I always had the "cannot find cudnn" error that cmake would throw. I went to the CMakeCache.txt file and inputted the path manualy.
The output file that cmake gave me was this:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
ocv_init_download: OpenCV source tree is not fetched as git repository. 3rdparty resources will be downloaded from github.com by default.
Detected processor: AMD64
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.1.3, BUILD = opencv-4.7.0-libjpeg-turbo
libjpeg-turbo(SIMD): SIMD extensions disabled: could not find NASM compiler.  Performance will suffer.
Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1). OpenJPEG will be built from sources
OpenJPEG: VERSION = 2.4.0, BUILD = opencv-4.7.0-openjp2-2.4.0
OpenJPEG libraries will be built from sources: libopenjp2 (version "2.4.0")
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2020.0.0 [2020.0.0 Gold]
at: J:/Petru/Opencv/Build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2020.0.0
at: J:/Petru/Opencv/Build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
CUDA detected: 12.1
CUDA: Using CUDA_ARCH_BIN=5.2
CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;-D_FORCE_INLINES
CUDA: MSVS generator is detected. Disabling CMake re-run checks (CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION=ON). You need to run CMake manually if updates are required.
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
Could NOT find LAPACK (missing: LAPACK_LIBRARIES) 
    Reason given by package: LAPACK could not be found because dependency BLAS could not be found.

Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 AWT JVM) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
Module opencv_alphamat disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
Julia not found. Not compiling Julia Bindings. 
Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
Tesseract:   NO
Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.lasx.cpp
Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.lasx.cpp
Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv-4.7.0/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.rvv.cpp
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.lasx.cpp
Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/int8layers/layers_common.lasx.cpp
imgcodecs: OpenEXR codec is disabled in runtime. Details: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21326
highgui: using builtin backend: WIN32UI
rgbd: Eigen support is disabled. Eigen is Required for Posegraph optimization
Building with NVIDIA Optical Flow API 2.0
Found 'misc' Python modules from J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv-4.7.0/modules/python/package/extra_modules
Found 'mat_wrapper;utils' Python modules from J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv-4.7.0/modules/core/misc/python/package
Found 'gapi' Python modules from J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv-4.7.0/modules/gapi/misc/python/package
Found 'misc' Python modules from J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv-4.7.0/modules/python/package/extra_modules
Found 'mat_wrapper;utils' Python modules from J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv-4.7.0/modules/core/misc/python/package
Found 'gapi' Python modules from J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv-4.7.0/modules/gapi/misc/python/package

General configuration for OpenCV 4.7.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv_contrib-4.7.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-03-18T17:57:16Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19044 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.26.0
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 17 2022
    CMake build tool:            F:/PetruUnity/IDE/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1934
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (18 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (34 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (8 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                F:/PetruUnity/IDE/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.34.31935.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  F:/PetruUnity/IDE/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /MP   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /MP /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO 
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          cudart_static.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib x64 cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64 -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat cvv freetype java julia matlab ovis python2 sfm viz
    Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.13)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   J:/Petru/Opencv/Build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                J:/Petru/Opencv/Build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 12.1, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             52
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.8.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                J:/Petru/Opencv/opencv-4.7.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 J:/Petru/Anaconda/python.exe (ver 3.9.13)
    Libraries:                   J:/Petru/Anaconda/libs/python39.lib (ver 3.9.13)
    numpy:                       J:/Petru/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.24.2)
    install path:                J:/Petru/Anaconda/Lib/site-packages/cv2/python-3.9

  Python (for build):            J:/Petru/Anaconda/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    J:/Petru/Opencv/Build/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done (16.5s)
Generating done (5.3s)
```

Given that cudnn and cuda appear on the log I have assumed that i would get the build with the gpu support, but it didn't build with it

this is my opencv build information (post instalation)

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.7.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.7.0

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     4.7.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-02-22T13:20:15Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.24.2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (32 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24245.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java julia matlab ovis python2 sfm ts viz
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.13)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/python.exe (ver 3.7.9)
    Libraries:                   C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/libs/python37.lib (ver 3.7.9)
    numpy:                       C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/python2.7.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include/win32 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.362-9/x64/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-install
```

Comment: Given that the path in error message (and second build info) is on D drive, and you're building on the J drive, the binary you're trying it with is not the one you built.

Comment: It is funny though, that when I search for that path in my explorer, it says "windows can't find D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.7/cmake-install check the spelling and try again "

Comment: Not really, it's the path where the source code used to build the binary was located at the time when it was built. And this one was built on someone else's computer (you must have installed it pre-built using some package manager -- it's not the first time I've seen this exact path even today). -- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=D%3A%2Fa%2Fopencv-python%2Fopencv-python%2F

Comment: What kind of python environment do you use? How do you install/deploy your self-built opencv in your python environment?

Comment: In addition to that environment problem, make sure to compile opencv also with OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON, meaning you will need alls the 3: -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
      -D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
      -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \ see https://learnopencv.com/opencv-dnn-with-gpu-support/

Comment: Earlier you mentioned a path that contains `win-amd64-3.7` (suggesting you're running it in Python 3.7) and the CMake report says it's using Python 3.9 from your Anaconda setup. My suspicion is that you're testing it in the wrong interpreter.